# How to reload a php function on javascript action?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

The thing is, in my website, there is a div tag which displays all the available values in a sql database. (Doing this using php). Now I want to reload this particular div tag at a javascript event.Ex: If I click on a html button, it must bring back all the values from the sql database and must display it there. (Implies reload a small php script in the page)

Can we do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes, you can do this. It's the functionallity the Web 2.0 is made of.

Comment: can you be more specific on how to achieve this...?

Comment: Keyword to google: _ajax_

Comment: Learn [`ajax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) :)

Comment: Try for yourself and come back when you have specific questions regarding your code (which you wrote by _yourself_ and not copied from elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

what i have understood is that you should make ajax request, below is jquery code, for that you will have to add jquery file.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"path_to_your_php_file_where_you_will_get_values_from_database_file.php",success:function(result){
    $("#div1").html(result);
  }});
});
```